# Two type of triggers on one window?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need your advice, really
In my task i need to aggregate events by two type of aggregation.
First type - is `onCount`, second type - is `onTime`.

If event is for `onCount` aggregation - it has fields number - `number` of event, and `totalCount` - what count of events we should accumulate before aggregate.

If event is for `onTime` aggregation - it has field `time` - it's `date` after which we should get all accumulate events and start aggregating.

I can groupped events by type, start window and set trigger:

```
stream
.keyBy(e => (e.clientSystemId, e.onMode))
.window(GlobalWindows.create())
.trigger(new WindowAggregationTrigger())
```

But in trigger i need to have state - total count or time.
And in best solution - i need two different triggers - first is about counting and second - is about time aggregation.

My question is - how beautifully to solve this problem?
When i need two triggers with different logic - first about counting, second- about time trigger.

I do not ask to solve the problem for me, I ask for advice.

We developing on Apache Flink 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to apply two different triggers in the same window operator, but you can implement a single trigger to distinguish the `onCount` and `onTime` cases.

However, I would recommend to split the stream into two streams (using `split()` or side outputs), apply window operators with different triggers on the splitted streams, and later `union()` the streams together (if that is necessary).